# Lambda expressions and higher-order functions

Tags: java, lambda, closures, java-8

How can I write with Java 8 with closures support a method that take as argument a function and return function as value?

Comment: [Closures for Java draft specification (by Neal Gafter and Peter von der Ahé)](http://javac.info/)

Comment: @Quoi That website relates to proposals that died years ago. For progress towards Java 8 implementation see http://lambdafaq.org

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java Lambda API the main class is [java.util.function.Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

You can use a reference to this interface in the same way as you would do with all other references: create that as variable, return it as a result of computation and so on.

Here is quite simple example which might help you:

```
    public class HigherOrder {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Function<Integer, Long> addOne = add(1L);

            System.out.println(addOne.apply(1)); //prints 2

            Arrays.asList("test", "new")
                    .parallelStream()  // suggestion for execution strategy
                    .map(camelize)     // call for static reference
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        private static Function<Integer, Long> add(long l) {
            return (Integer i) -> l + i;
        }

        private static Function<String, String> camelize = (str) -> str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    }
```

If you need to pass more then 1 parameter, please take a look into `compose` method, but its usage is quite tricky.

In general from my opinion closures and lambdas in Java is basically syntax-sugar, and they seem to not have all capabilities of functional programming.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Do you know if is it applicable this: add(8)(10) because do this is very boring: add(8).apply(10)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be not allowed, at least - now

Comment: n1ckolas, excuse me, I don't find any compose method... where can I look for an example to write a Function with more parameters?

Comment: Interface `java.util.function.Function` has method `compose`, which you can use something in this way: `Function other = addOne.compose(()->{})`, but as I told before, this seems to be fairly tricky

Comment: No, it hasn't. Look at: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html

Comment: I have it in my lambda-b78: http://download.java.net/lambda/b76/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose%28java.util.function.Function%29

Comment: Yes, it's not been taken away!  That documentation has been produced with a version of JavaDoc that doesn't list default methods.  For an up-to-date (and complete!) version, see http://lambdadoc.net/api, a resource of [the Lambda FAQ](http://lambdafaq.org)

Comment: IMO, doing FP in java look like a faked one.