# generate high order functions in java with access specifiers

Tags: javascript, java

I found a way as java 8 supports higher order functions: [Lambda expressions and higher-order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198979/lambda-expressions-and-higher-order-functions)

like in javascript:

```
funcArr = ["abc","def"];
funcArr.forEach(function(x){
   eval(x+"=function(){console.log('new func');}");
}
```

Now my query is if I use this approach mentioned in the above answer, can I specify the access modifiers for the functions created

Comment: looking for anonymous implementations ??

Comment: not anonymous, need well defined functions generated

Comment: Can you explain the reason you need it? the only thing I could think of is java8 functional interfaces + lambdas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be useful.

```
   Arrays.asList("abc", "def").forEach(func -> {
            try {
                new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval(func + "=function(){console.log('new func');}");
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                //catch
            }
        });
```

Comment: I found another way as java 8 supports higher order functions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198979/lambda-expressions-and-higher-order-functions

Now my query is if I use this approach mentioned in the above answer, can I specify the access modifiers for the functions created